# R: matching rows of strings of 2 matrices

Tags: r

I am working with IP address data and I read in the data as strings. For simplicity, I conjure up an easy example. I tried to match the rows of strings of matrix "m" to those in matrix "abc". But I kept failing to get correct output.

```
> abc <- matrix(c("dog", "king", "bee", "cat", "apple","eel", "crab", "ball","soap","crazy"), nrow = 5)
> abc
     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "dog"   "eel"  
[2,] "king"  "crab" 
[3,] "bee"   "ball" 
[4,] "cat"   "soap" 
[5,] "apple" "crazy"

> m <- matrix(c("dog", "bee","eel","ball" ), nrow = 2)
> m
     [,1]  [,2]  
[1,] "dog" "eel" 
[2,] "bee" "ball"
```

I get output, which doesnt make any sense:

```
> match(data.frame(t(abc)), data.frame(t(m)))
[1] 1 2 2 1 1
```

I am expecting output to be 
[1] 1 NA 2 NA NA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a `factor` issue, try this instead:

```
match(data.frame(t(abc), stringsAsFactors = F),
      data.frame(t(m), stringsAsFactors = F))
#[1]  1 NA  2 NA NA
```

Comment: How can it be a "factor issue" if these are matrices?

Comment: the strings become `factor`s when converted to a `data.frame`

Comment: I'm guessing this is a language issue :) I meant that it's not working because those are factors, not that there is some sort of a problem with factors.

Comment: I was going to suggest side stepping the factor problem by skipping data frames entirely: `match(split(abc,seq_len(nrow(abc))),split(m,seq_len(nrow(m))))`, or something.

Comment: I'm convinced. It did become a "factor issue". I should have looked at the intermediate results more carefully. @joran's code will probably be faster but not as easy to understand.